# How to swap (translate) values inside a vector

Tags: r, vector, swap

Let

```
vetA <- c(1,2,1,2,1,3,4,1,2,3,2,1,4)
```

What are the possibilities so I could do the following swap?
Swap:

- 1 `-->` 3
- 2 `-->` 4
- 3 `-->` 2
- 4 `-->` 1

I have tried this:

```
vetB <- as.factor(vetA)
levels(vetB) <- c(3,4,2,1)
vetA <- as.integer(vetB)

# because
print(vetB)
# [1] 3 4 3 4 3 2 1 3 4 2 4 3 1
#Levels: 3 4 2 1
```

It didn't work. Could you please give me a hand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible option would be to use `match`:

```
vetA <- c(1,2,1,2,1,3,4,1,2,3,2,1,4)
old=c(1,2,3,4)
new=c(3,4,2,1)
new[match(vetA,old)]
```

Output:

```
3 4 3 4 3 2 1 3 4 2 4 3 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works without `match()` because the values that you want to replace are simply `1:4`. In most other situations (e.g., when the values are not numeric, or for an integer sequence starting at any other value than 1), it only works with `match()`.

Answer (score 9):

If you converted your factor vector to character before converting it to integer, your code will work. Notice that factor is internally stored as integer, so `as.integer(vetB)` would return its integer levels.

```
vetA <- c(1,2,1,2,1,3,4,1,2,3,2,1,4)

vetB <- as.factor(vetA)
levels(vetB) <- c(3,4,2,1)
vetA <- as.integer(as.character(vetB))
vetA
# [1] 3 4 3 4 3 2 1 3 4 2 4 3 1
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create a look-up table:

```
vetA <- c(1,2,1,2,1,3,4,1,2,3,2,1,4)
lookup <- setNames(c(3, 4, 2, 1), 1:4)
lookup[vetA]
## 1 2 1 2 1 3 4 1 2 3 2 1 4 
## 3 4 3 4 3 2 1 3 4 2 4 3 1
```

The values of `lookup` are the new values, while the names are set to the old values. You can then use your vector `vetA` as index to pick the new values.

Since the values that you replace are simply `c(1, 2, 3, 4)`, there is actually no need to set the names explicitly and you could get the same result simply with

```
c(3, 4, 2, 1)[vetA]
## [1] 3 4 3 4 3 2 1 3 4 2 4 3 1
```

However, the solution above will also work in situations where the values that you replace are not just an integer sequence.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply do

```
new[order(old)][vetA]

# [1] 3 4 3 4 3 2 1 3 4 2 4 3 1
```

where

```
vetA <- c(1,2,1,2,1,3,4,1,2,3,2,1,4)
old <- c(1,2,3,4)
new <- c(3,4,2,1)
```

---

Note: This would work—as well as the accepted answer by @Florian—even if the vector `old` is *not* sorted. The other two answers won't work in which case. For example if

```
old <- c(3,2,1,4)
new <- c(3,4,2,1)
```